# - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'get_staticObjects'

Tags: javascript

I am new to Java and ECMA script. I am trying small program with ECMA script but  am getting references and Microsoft JScript runtime error. Please assist. My code is below

```js
//Code in ASCX file.
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../_layouts/SP.Core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../_layouts/SP.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Host.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="fun();" />

//Code in Host.js
function fun() {
    debugger;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(url);
            var web = clientContext.get_web();//This is throwing error "- Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'get_staticObjects'"

            clientContext.load(web);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);

            function success() {
                alert("success");
            }

            function fail() {
                alert("fail");
            }

        });
}
```

Comment: Solved:
Finally, SP.js and its related files were loaded with below code.
`code`
 var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

            //Build absolute path to the layouts root with the spHostUrl
            var layoutsRoot = url + '/_layouts/15/';
            $.getScript(layoutsRoot + "SP.Core.js", function ()
            {
                $.getScript(layoutsRoot + "SP.Runtime.js", function ()
                {
                    $.getScript(layoutsRoot + "SP.js", createListItem);
                }
            )
            });